# DTD of Word Xml Document

Tags: validation, ms-word, dtd

When I get an xml document from ms word, I need to validate it programmatically using dtd.
Since a simple word document has a large xml file, how can I get a dtd file of that xml document?

Comment: Which "Word XML"? There are multiple XML based output formats from Word: Docx, 2003 XML, ODT?

Comment: its a word xml document which is also one of the output formats

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments you are using the 2003 "XML" output format, that schema is available from microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=101